# Update on Huawei Y6

Tags: huawei

hi is there a way I can update my Huawei Y6 from android 5.1, emui 3.1 to a higher system please help.

Thank .

kind regards

Comment: Check in settings under *about device* there should be an option to check for updates.

Comment: [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/huawei-y6/development) - I just flashed LineageOS on someone else's Y6 not long ago. The official unlocking procedure takes 14 days though, mind you.